# Are all open sets open intervals?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, elementary-set-theory

Are all open sets open intervals? If not, provide an example. I think that all open intervals are open sets but not the other way around, but couldn't find an example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You haven't mentioned it, but I understand that you're talking about intervals on $\mathbb R$.

**Are all open intervals open sets?** Yes.

Open intervals on $\mathbb R$ are of the form $(a,b)$, where we let $a,b$ take on values in $[-\infty,\infty]$.  You can check that these are open sets.

**Are all open sets open intervals?** No!

The union of two open sets is open (more generally, any arbitrary union of open sets is open). So, take $(0,1)$ and $(2,3)$. These are *open intervals*, hence open sets. From what we just said, $(0,1) \cup (2,3)$ is also an open *set*, but not an open interval (let alone an open interval, this isn't even an interval).

---

**P.S.** *What you should know:*
When is $A\subset \Bbb R$ open?
$A\subset \Bbb R$ is open if for every $x\in A$, there exists some $\epsilon > 0$ so that $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon) \subset A$. In other words, for every point in $A$, you can find a neighborhood of that point which is contained in $A$.

Comment: When is an open set an open interval?

Comment: Connected open sets are open intervals.

Comment: Even in $\mathbb R^n$? Is this a sufficient condition?

Comment: No, this is only for $\Bbb R$. In $\Bbb R$, it so happens that the connected sets are exactly the intervals. On $\Bbb R^n$, I don't think you can extend the same notion. What would you call an interval on $\Bbb R^n$ anyway? If you're thinking something of the form $(a_1,b_1) \times \ldots \times (a_n,b_n)$ - then I don't think that'll work always. For example, $\Bbb R^2\setminus \{0\}$ is path-connected (hence connected), but can you really write it as a cartesian product of intervals from $\Bbb R$? I don't think so.

Comment: Also, is this a necessary and sufficient condition in $\mathbb R$?

Comment: In $\Bbb R$, it is **necessary and sufficient**, without a doubt. Here's why: (1) Open intervals are open sets, and they are connected because they are intervals. (2) Connected sets in $\Bbb R$ are exactly the intervals, and a connected open set is therefore an open interval!

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Cheers.

Comment: so can I say that  $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is open if and only if $S$ is the union of open intervals?

Comment: @MengfanMa Correct. A countable union. This is due to separability.

Comment: So where can I find a formal proof for this?

Comment: @MengfanMa Maybe think about it some more? It's not too hard. Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 4):

This question ultimately depends on the set and topology. Since the tag is real-analysis, I take it your talking about $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology. In that case, you're correct that all open intervals are open sets, whereas not every open set is an open interval. Take for example $E:=(1,2)\cup(4,5)$. Then $E$ is open, as the union of open sets, but is not an interval.